# Office 2016 Installation Using PlayOnLinux

Tags: playonlinux, microsoft-office, ubuntu-mate

I have bought a license for Office 2016 Pro Plus from Microsoft. How can I install the same on Ubuntu MATE using PlayOnLinux?

When I try, it keeps throwing error as follows.

```
Unhandled exception: unimplemented function KERNEL32.dll.SetWaitableTimerEx called in 64-bit code (0x00007f0ded366bbc).
Register dump:
 rip:00007f0ded366bbc rsp:00000000003cd440 rbp:00000000003cd700 eflags:00000202 (   - --  I   - - - )
 rax:0000000000000000 rbx:00000000003cd460 rcx:00000000003cd460 rdx:00000001400d21f5
 rsi:00000001402a7a5c rdi:00000001402a6368  r8:0000000000000000  r9:0000000000000000 r10:00000000000000b4
 r11:0000000000000246 r12:00000000003ce0c0 r13:ffffffffffffff01 r14:00000000000000ac r15:0000000000000000
Stack dump:
0x00000000003cd440:  00000000003cd460 0000000000000000
0x00000000003cd450:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000003cd460:  0000000180000100 0000000000000000
0x00000000003cd470:  00007f0ded366bbc 0000000000000002
0x00000000003cd480:  00000001402a6368 00000001402a7a5c
0x00000000003cd490:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000003cd4a0:  0000000000000000 00000000003cd560
0x00000000003cd4b0:  0000000000090d00 0000000000090ef0
0x00000000003cd4c0:  00000000003cd700 00000001400d1f8f
0x00000000003cd4d0:  0000000140381a80 0000000000000000
0x00000000003cd4e0:  0000000140381a80 00000001400d2f23
0x00000000003cd4f0:  00000000003cd560 68ce7144bf36e300
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00007f0ded366bbc in ntdll (+0x36bbc) (0x00000000003cd700)
  1 0x00000001400d21f5 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xd21f4) (0x00000000003cd700)
  2 0x00000001400d2107 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xd2106) (0x00000000003cd700)
  3 0x00000001400d1b0c in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xd1b0b) (0x00000000003cd700)
  4 0x0000000140112976 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x112975) (0x00000000003cd7d0)
  5 0x000000014011512d in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x11512c) (0x00000000003cd7d0)
  6 0x000000014011826c in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x11826b) (0x00000000003cd7d0)
  7 0x00000001401182f5 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x1182f4) (0x00000000003cd7d0)
  8 0x0000000140116f84 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x116f83) (0x00000000003cd930)
  9 0x000000014011a541 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_TXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX _TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x11a540) (0x00000000003ce039)
  10 0x000000014005e78e in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x5e78d) (0x00000000003ce039)
  11 0x000000014005e240 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x5e23f) (0x00000000003ce039)
  12 0x000000014005e0e2 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x5e0e1) (0x00000000003ce149)
  13 0x000000014001dfa5 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x1dfa4) (0x00000000003ce320)
  14 0x000000014001d7ae in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0x1d7ad) (0x00000000003ce320)
  15 0x00000001400a35d3 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xa35d2) (0x00000000003ce320)
  16 0x00000001400a4a71 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xa4a70) (0x00000000003ce320)
  17 0x00000001400a35d3 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xa35d2) (0x00000000003ce4b8)
  18 0x00000001400b6a9f in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xb6a9e) (0x00000000003ce4b8)
  19 0x00000001400b783f in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xb783e) (0x00000000003ce4b8)
  20 0x00000001400b5399 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xb5398) (0x00000000003ce4b8)
  21 0x00000001400b5ad8 in setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe (+0xb5ad7) (0x00000000003ce570)
  22 0x00007f0ded39d513 call_thread_func+0xd2() in ntdll (0x00000001400b5a80)
  23 0x00007f0ded3969aa RtlRaiseException+0x7d() in ntdll (0x00000001400b5a80)
  24 0x00007f0ded3a59a9 in ntdll (+0x759a8) (0x00000001400b5a80)
  25 0x00007f0dedbe06fa start_thread+0xc9() in libpthread.so.0 (0x0000000000000000)
  26 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  27 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  28 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  29 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  30 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  31 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  32 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  33 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  34 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  35 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  36 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  37 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  38 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  39 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  40 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  41 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  42 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  43 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  44 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  45 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  46 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  47 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  48 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  49 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  50 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  51 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  52 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  53 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  54 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  55 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  56 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  57 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  58 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  59 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  60 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  61 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  62 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  63 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  64 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  65 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  66 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  67 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  68 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  69 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  70 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  71 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  72 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  73 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  74 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  75 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  76 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  77 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  78 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  79 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  80 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  81 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  82 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  83 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  84 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  85 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  86 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  87 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  88 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  89 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  90 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  91 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  92 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  93 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  94 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  95 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  96 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  97 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  98 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  99 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  100 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  101 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  102 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  103 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  104 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  105 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  106 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  107 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  108 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  109 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  110 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  111 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  112 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  113 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  114 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  115 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  116 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  117 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  118 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  119 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  120 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  121 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  122 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  123 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  124 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  125 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  126 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  127 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  128 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  129 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  130 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  131 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  132 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  133 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  134 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  135 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  136 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  137 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  138 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  139 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  140 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  141 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  142 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  143 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  144 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  145 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  146 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  147 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  148 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  149 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  150 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  151 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  152 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  153 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  154 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  155 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  156 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  157 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  158 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  159 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  160 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  161 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  162 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  163 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  164 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  165 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  166 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  167 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  168 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  169 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  170 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  171 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  172 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  173 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  174 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  175 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  176 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  177 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  178 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  179 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  180 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  181 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  182 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  183 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  184 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  185 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  186 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  187 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  188 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  189 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  190 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  191 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  192 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  193 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  194 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  195 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  196 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  197 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  198 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  199 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
  200 0x00007f0ded915b5d __clone+0x6c() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)
0x00007f0ded366bbc: addq    $20,%rsp
Modules:
Module  Address                 Debug info  Name (94 modules)
ELF         7b800000-        7bc7c000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE          7b820000-        7bc7c000   \               kernel32
ELF         7be00000-        7c103000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
PE         140000000-       140449000   Export          setup.x64.en-us_proplusretail_tvZ:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX_TX_SG_act_1_.exe
ELF     7f0ddfb78000-    7f0ddfd80000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF     7f0ddfd80000-    7f0de0000000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF     7f0de412c000-    7f0de435f000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF     7f0de435f000-    7f0de4595000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF     7f0de4595000-    7f0de47a8000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF     7f0de47a8000-    7f0de49db000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF     7f0de49db000-    7f0de4c40000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF     7f0de4c40000-    7f0de4f71000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF     7f0de4f90000-    7f0de51c1000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de4fa0000-    7f0de51c1000   \               netapi32
ELF     7f0de51c1000-    7f0de53fa000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de51d0000-    7f0de53fa000   \               secur32
ELF     7f0de53fa000-    7f0de5634000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de5400000-    7f0de5634000   \               uxtheme
ELF     7f0de5634000-    7f0de585f000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de5640000-    7f0de585f000   \               mpr
ELF     7f0de585f000-    7f0de5ae6000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de5870000-    7f0de5ae6000   \               wininet
ELF     7f0de5ae6000-    7f0de5df3000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de5af0000-    7f0de5df3000   \               comctl32
ELF     7f0de5df3000-    7f0de6258000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de5e10000-    7f0de6258000   \               shell32
ELF     7f0de6258000-    7f0de6518000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de6270000-    7f0de6518000   \               urlmon
ELF     7f0de6518000-    7f0de6827000   Deferred        msi<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de6530000-    7f0de6827000   \               msi
ELF     7f0de686d000-    7f0de6a73000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF     7f0de6a73000-    7f0de6c7d000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF     7f0de6c7d000-    7f0de6e8d000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF     7f0de6e8d000-    7f0de7090000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF     7f0de7090000-    7f0de729b000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF     7f0de729b000-    7f0de74a5000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF     7f0de74a5000-    7f0de76ab000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF     7f0de76ab000-    7f0de78ae000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF     7f0de78ae000-    7f0de7ab4000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF     7f0de7ab4000-    7f0de7cb8000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF     7f0de7cb8000-    7f0de7eda000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF     7f0de7eda000-    7f0de8214000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF     7f0de8214000-    7f0de8426000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF     7f0de8445000-    7f0de86e6000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de8460000-    7f0de86e6000   \               winex11
ELF     7f0de87e2000-    7f0de8a0b000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF     7f0de8a0b000-    7f0de8c4e000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF     7f0de8c4e000-    7f0de8e73000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF     7f0de8e73000-    7f0de911d000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF     7f0de911d000-    7f0de9345000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de9120000-    7f0de9345000   \               iphlpapi
ELF     7f0de9345000-    7f0de95c2000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de9350000-    7f0de95c2000   \               setupapi
ELF     7f0de95c2000-    7f0de98ac000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de95d0000-    7f0de98ac000   \               crypt32
ELF     7f0de98ac000-    7f0de9ae9000   Deferred        wintrust<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de98b0000-    7f0de9ae9000   \               wintrust
ELF     7f0de9ae9000-    7f0de9d03000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF     7f0de9d03000-    7f0de9f23000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de9d10000-    7f0de9f23000   \               cabinet
ELF     7f0de9f23000-    7f0dea1b6000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE      7f0de9f40000-    7f0dea1b6000   \               shlwapi
ELF     7f0dea1b6000-    7f0dea463000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE      7f0dea1d0000-    7f0dea463000   \               gdiplus
ELF     7f0dea463000-    7f0dea69d000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0dea470000-    7f0dea69d000   \               ws2_32
ELF     7f0dea69d000-    7f0deaa1f000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0dea6c0000-    7f0deaa1f000   \               oleaut32
ELF     7f0deaa1f000-    7f0deacb2000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE      7f0deaa30000-    7f0deacb2000   \               rpcrt4
ELF     7f0deacb2000-    7f0deaecc000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE      7f0deacc0000-    7f0deaecc000   \               version
ELF     7f0deaecc000-    7f0deb232000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0deaee0000-    7f0deb232000   \               gdi32
ELF     7f0deb232000-    7f0deb5e3000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0deb250000-    7f0deb5e3000   \               user32
ELF     7f0deb5e3000-    7f0deb96a000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0deb610000-    7f0deb96a000   \               ole32
ELF     7f0deb96a000-    7f0debbf1000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE      7f0deb980000-    7f0debbf1000   \               advapi32
ELF     7f0debbf1000-    7f0debe03000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF     7f0debe03000-    7f0dec00f000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF     7f0dec00f000-    7f0dec228000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF     7f0dec228000-    7f0dec431000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF     7f0decdf0000-    7f0ded006000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF     7f0ded006000-    7f0ded30f000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF     7f0ded30f000-    7f0ded608000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE      7f0ded330000-    7f0ded608000   \               ntdll
ELF     7f0ded60b000-    7f0ded80f000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF     7f0ded80f000-    7f0dedbd8000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF     7f0dedbd9000-    7f0deddf6000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF     7f0dede15000-    7f0dee1b9000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF     7f0dee1bb000-    7f0dee3e3000   Deferred        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ELF     7ffd9c9f0000-    7ffd9c9f1000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    00000018    0
    00000016    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001b    0
00000021 (D) Z:\home\Softwares\Office2016\Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_TXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX _TX_SG_act_1_.exe
    00000027    0
    00000026    0 <==
    00000022    0
00000023 explorer.exe
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
```

System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: x86_64
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-22-generic

Comment: You probably will not be able to do that reliably without running it in a VM (which will cost you another MS license).

Answer (score 9):

According to playonlinux.com, Office 2016 is not supported.

You do however have some alternatives:

1. Run Office 2016 in a virtual machine with Windows.
2. Office 2013 might work with PlayOnLinux on your machine. It works on
   my hardware, but it does not work on all.
3. Office 2010 is supported by PlayOnLinux.
4. You can use the online version of Office. There is a free version, but in
   order to get all functionality you will have to pay
   a monthly subscription of Office 365 to Microsoft. The online
   version of Word and Powerpoint are available as apps in Chrome Web
   Store.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get Office 2016 to work on PlayOnLinux: 
You can check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975104/how-do-i-install-ms-office-2016-on-playonlinux/1077935#1077935) on Askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use POL wine 3.14 (latest 3.19 or 3.0 /3.4 did not work for me) on Ubuntu 18.04 and steps 1-5 [post Kevin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975104/how-do-i-install-ms-office-2016-on-playonlinux/1077935#1077935) to get MS Office 2016 (Word/Excel/Powerpoint) started. If you download the complete office 2016 IMG file, the installation includes your personal license and is already activated on start.