# Where to install software using playonlinux?

Tags: 18.04, wine, playonlinux

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4 LTS, and very new to playonlinux/wine. I have been trying to install a software (microsoft office 2010 and then 2016) using both playonlinux/wine manually by choosing the option "Install a non-listed program". My trials failed everytime. After checking, I found that the default file location for the installation is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office, which means nothing for ubuntu. This could be the reason why the installation fails. So, where should the location be in my case?

Update about my installation: When installing using the menu "Office" in playonlinux and choosing the option "Microsoft Office 2010" from the list, everything turned out to be okay. But that's not the case for "Microsoft Office 2016".

Comment: Please click [edit] to let us know these facts. 1) Which OS is installed (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.)? 2) Which release number?  3) Which version of Microsoft Office?   https://www.winehq.org/search?q=microsoft+office Different versions require different instructions, you see. Please do not use Add Comment; Comments are a channel from us to you, whereas the Question should contain all the facts you have about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The PlayOnLinux installs windows programs to the special folders (or prefixes). By default each program is installed in its separate wineprefix.

The wine-prefixes are located at `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/` in your home folder. The wine-prefix for an application contains `drive_c` folder (on `.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/app-name/drive_c` path) with contents of virtual `C:\` drive.

PlayOnLinux have many installation scripts to create shortcuts in the user-friendly way. I would recommend to use them:

[image: mso]

MSO 2016 is too new, so it may not work on Wine yet. You can try to follow [other Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/975104/66509) if default method fails.

---

By the way if you do not need to use OLE objects and MS Word extensions like MathType of Adobe PDFMaker then you can learn LibreOffice and use it instead.