# I have install MS Office 2016 with Wine but MS Fonts are not available

Tags: wine, fonts, playonlinux, microsoft

I followed instructions in this thread ([How do I install MS Office 2016 on PlayOnLinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975104/how-do-i-install-ms-office-2016-on-playonlinux/1233780#1233780?newreg=5e6a187ff86049f2856d3f9122044978)) to install MS Office 2016 using POL / Wine. The process worked without any issues. Now when I load documents in MS Office, the original document fonts used are not working.

I have installed MS fonts and Truetype fonts both outside and inside of POL. The fonts required are available to LibreOffice but they will not work in MS Office?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the ubuntu restricted extras package? `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I do have ubuntu-restricted-extras installed.

I have managed to get it working now. A rather predictable answer, I rebooted and everything was working. So used to not having to reboot on Ubuntu to get things working.

If anyone is looking to get MS Office 2016 working on Ubuntu, I can recommend the article posted above. It works perfectly and not difficult to get working.