# Office 2016 on POL - Powerpoint Start Issue

Tags: 20.04, 32-bit, microsoft-office

I tried to install Office 2016 on Ubuntu 20.04 following the manual installation method described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1233780. The installation worked quite well and most applications run well as far as I can see. Only Powerpoint will not start.

One thing I could not do was Step 8 in the "Install Office" section:

> Using Nautilus go to folder `drive_c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/ClickToRun/` and copy `AppvIsvSubsystems32.dll`
> and `C2R32.dll` to `drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/`.

**My Installation doesn't have a folder "ClickToRun"** and I couldn't find the respective dll-files in the entire Playonlinux-drive either. I also do not have the target directory (...root/Office16) in my POL installation.

How to get Powerpoint started?

Here are the program error details:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x027fd79b).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:027fd79b ESP:0033f598 EBP:0033f5a4 EFLAGS:00210246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:00000008 EBX:0033f620 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000000
 ESI:031be210 EDI:00000003
Stack dump:
0x0033f598:  025acd26 0033f620 011d9728 0033f5d0
0x0033f5a8:  025ac97e 0033f620 e5895516 10859c1c
0x0033f5b8:  0033f620 10a45788 0033f5b0 0033faf0
0x0033f5c8:  02ecb0f3 00000000 0033f5e0 025ad35f
0x0033f5d8:  011d9f60 00000003 0033f5f4 0200994f
0x0033f5e8:  0033f620 00000003 00000003 0033f604
Backtrace:
=>0 0x027fd79b in mso (+0x25d79b) (0x0033f5a4)
  1 0x025ac97e in mso (+0xc97d) (0x0033f5d0)
  2 0x025ad35f in mso (+0xd35e) (0x0033f5e0)
  3 0x0200994f in mso99lwin32client (+0x994e) (0x0033f5f4)
  4 0x025ad25f in mso (+0xd25e) (0x0033f604)
  5 0x025aead6 in mso (+0xead5) (0x0033f650)
  6 0x025aea65 in mso (+0xea64) (0x0033f674)
  7 0x10007190 in ppcore (+0x718f) (0x0033facc)
  8 0x10006940 in ppcore (+0x693f) (0x0033fafc)
  9 0x10005f80 in ppcore (+0x5f7f) (0x0033fb28)
  10 0x10006044 in ppcore (+0x6043) (0x0033fb54)
  11 0x100093d5 in ppcore (+0x93d4) (0x0033fb84)
  12 0x100093a5 in ppcore (+0x93a4) (0x0033fb9c)
  13 0x1000601b in ppcore (+0x601a) (0x0033fdf4)
  14 0x100065da in ppcore (+0x65d9) (0x0033fe68)
  15 0x004016ed in powerpnt (+0x16ec) (0x0033fe74)
  16 0x004016bf in powerpnt (+0x16be) (0x0033fec0)
  17 0x7b4664fc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fed8)
  18 0x7b467bc6 start_process+0x105() in kernel32 (0x0033ffd8)
  19 0x7b46650a start_process_wrapper+0x9() in kernel32 (0x0033ffec)
0x027fd79b: movl    $0x1,0x00000000
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (204 modules)
PE    400000-  5c5000   Export          powerpnt
PE    5d0000- 11c2000   Deferred        oart
PE   13f0000- 15c5000   Deferred        mso20win32client
PE   15d0000- 18d2000   Deferred        mso30win32client
PE   18e0000- 1ff5000   Deferred        mso40uiwin32client
PE   2000000- 2598000   Export          mso99lwin32client
PE   25a0000- 3352000   Export          mso
PE   90b0000- 91df000   Deferred        ppintl
PE   91e0000- 931a000   Deferred        ppresources
PE  10000000-10b5f000   Export          ppcore
ELF 7a800000-7a93e000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a93e000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b400000-7b7f3000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7f3000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bd09000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bd09000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d90a000-7d912000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d912000-7d91f000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d91f000-7d934000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d934000-7d939000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d939000-7d948000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d948000-7d954000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d954000-7d95c000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d95c000-7d961000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d961000-7d980000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7d980000-7d988000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d988000-7d98e000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d98e000-7d9bd000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d9bd000-7db0c000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7db0c000-7db23000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7db4c000-7dbe5000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7db60000-7dbe5000   \               winex11
ELF 7dbe5000-7dc04000   Deferred        concrt140<elf>
  \-PE  7dbf0000-7dc04000   \               concrt140
ELF 7dc04000-7dc2a000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dc10000-7dc2a000   \               imm32
ELF 7dd04000-7dd30000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd30000-7dd7e000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dd7e000-7dd9c000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7dd9c000-7dddb000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7dddb000-7dea1000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7deca000-7dede000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7ded0000-7dede000   \               api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0
ELF 7dede000-7df55000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7def0000-7df55000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7df55000-7dff1000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7df60000-7dff1000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7dff1000-7e008000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e000000-7e008000   \               api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0
ELF 7e008000-7e01e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e010000-7e01e000   \               api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0
ELF 7e01e000-7e032000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e020000-7e032000   \               api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0
ELF 7e032000-7e048000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e040000-7e048000   \               api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0
ELF 7e048000-7e143000   Deferred        msvcr120<elf>
  \-PE  7e060000-7e143000   \               msvcr120
ELF 7e143000-7e268000   Deferred        msvcp140<elf>
  \-PE  7e180000-7e268000   \               msvcp140
ELF 7e268000-7e2ef000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e270000-7e2ef000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e2ef000-7e309000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e2f0000-7e309000   \               version
ELF 7e309000-7e512000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e320000-7e512000   \               user32
ELF 7e512000-7e679000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e530000-7e679000   \               ole32
ELF 7e679000-7e7c9000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e690000-7e7c9000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e7c9000-7e843000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e7e0000-7e843000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e843000-7e857000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e850000-7e857000   \               api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0
ELF 7e857000-7e86b000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e860000-7e86b000   \               api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0
ELF 7e86b000-7e881000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e870000-7e881000   \               api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0
ELF 7e881000-7e89a000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e890000-7e89a000   \               api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0
ELF 7e89a000-7e8b0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7e8a0000-7e8b0000   \               api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0
ELF 7e8b0000-7e9b8000   Deferred        ucrtbase<elf>
  \-PE  7e8d0000-7e9b8000   \               ucrtbase
ELF 7ee86000-7ee9b000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ee9b000-7eeb8000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7eeb8000-7eec7000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7eec7000-7eed2000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7eed2000-7efd7000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe0000-7efea000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7efea000-7f000000   Deferred        vcruntime140<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               vcruntime140
ELF ed143000-ed1b4000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  ed150000-ed1b4000   \               dbghelp
ELF ed1b4000-ed1ec000   Deferred        mscoree<elf>
  \-PE  ed1c0000-ed1ec000   \               mscoree
ELF ed350000-ed3a6000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF ed3a6000-ed3b5000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF ed3b5000-ed496000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF ed496000-ed526000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF ed526000-ed6a8000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
ELF ed6a8000-ed800000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF ed800000-eda00000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF edb01000-edb35000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF edb5e000-edb97000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.5
ELF edb97000-edbd7000   Deferred        libnettle.so.7
ELF edbe5000-edc00000   Deferred        kerberos<elf>
  \-PE  edbf0000-edc00000   \               kerberos
ELF ee003000-ee023000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF ee023000-ee08f000   Deferred        dwrite<elf>
  \-PE  ee030000-ee08f000   \               dwrite
ELF eea04000-eea1d000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF ef2bd000-ef2d4000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF ef2d4000-ef300000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  ef2e0000-ef300000   \               iphlpapi
ELF ef406000-ef40c000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF ef40c000-ef412000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF f0703000-f0734000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  f0710000-f0734000   \               netapi32
ELF f0734000-f076b000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  f0740000-f076b000   \               secur32
ELF f0f6c000-f0f95000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.6
ELF f0f95000-f0fa0000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF f0fa0000-f0fd8000   Deferred        libedit.so.2
ELF f0fd8000-f0fe2000   Deferred        libffi.so.7
ELF f0fe2000-f0fed000   Deferred        libatomic.so.1
ELF f0fed000-f100c000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF f11ea000-f1247000   Deferred        libvulkan.so.1
ELF f1247000-f1251000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF f1251000-f125e000   Deferred        libdrm_amdgpu.so.1
ELF f125e000-f127c000   Deferred        libelf.so.1
ELF f127c000-f1323000   Deferred        libzstd.so.1
ELF f1323000-f54f4000   Deferred        libllvm-10.so.1
ELF f551d000-f6ce3000   Deferred        r600_dri.so
ELF f6ce3000-f6ce6000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF f6ce6000-f6cef000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF f6cef000-f6cf4000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF f6cf4000-f6cfa000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF f6cfa000-f6cff000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF f6cff000-f6d1e000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF f6d1e000-f6d34000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF f6d34000-f6d5d000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF f6d5d000-f6ddd000   Deferred        libglx_mesa.so.0
ELF f6ddd000-f6e19000   Deferred        libglx.so.0
ELF f6e19000-f6e96000   Deferred        libgldispatch.so.0
ELF f6e96000-f6f03000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF f6f03000-f6f13000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF f6f13000-f6f25000   Deferred        libsensors.so.5
ELF f6f2c000-f6f44000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  f6f30000-f6f44000   \               wtsapi32
ELF f6f44000-f6fc5000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_43<elf>
  \-PE  f6f50000-f6fc5000   \               d3dcompiler_43
ELF f6fc5000-f700d000   Deferred        d3d10<elf>
  \-PE  f6fd0000-f700d000   \               d3d10
ELF f700d000-f717c000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  f7020000-f717c000   \               wined3d
ELF f717c000-f71ab000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE  f7180000-f71ab000   \               dxgi
ELF f71ab000-f721b000   Deferred        d3d11<elf>
  \-PE  f71b0000-f721b000   \               d3d11
ELF f721b000-f7231000   Deferred        d3d10core<elf>
  \-PE  f7220000-f7231000   \               d3d10core
ELF f7231000-f7247000   Deferred        d3d10_1<elf>
  \-PE  f7240000-f7247000   \               d3d10_1
ELF f7247000-f72a8000   Deferred        d2d1<elf>
  \-PE  f7250000-f72a8000   \               d2d1
ELF f72a8000-f72e0000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  f72b0000-f72e0000   \               uxtheme
ELF f72e0000-f7306000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE  f72f0000-f7306000   \               cabinet
ELF f7306000-f7352000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  f7310000-f7352000   \               usp10
ELF f7352000-f74a2000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  f7360000-f74a2000   \               comctl32
ELF f74a2000-f74dc000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  f74b0000-f74dc000   \               ws2_32
ELF f74dc000-f7504000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  f74e0000-f7504000   \               mpr
ELF f7504000-f7585000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  f7510000-f7585000   \               wininet
ELF f7585000-f77dd000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  f7590000-f77dd000   \               shell32
ELF f77dd000-f787e000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  f77f0000-f787e000   \               urlmon
ELF f787e000-f79a7000   Deferred        msi<elf>
  \-PE  f7890000-f79a7000   \               msi
ELF f79a7000-f79bc000   Deferred        slc<elf>
  \-PE  f79b0000-f79bc000   \               slc
ELF f79bc000-f79d0000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  f79c0000-f79d0000   \               msimg32
ELF f79d0000-f79e4000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  f79e0000-f79e4000   \               api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0
ELF f79e4000-f7b20000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  f7a00000-f7b20000   \               oleaut32
ELF f7b29000-f7b2f000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7b2f000-f7d1d000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7d1d000-f7d40000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7d40000-f7d47000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF f7d47000-f7d4c000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF f7d4c000-f7d60000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  f7d50000-f7d60000   \               api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0
ELF f7d69000-f7f21000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7f23000-f7f50000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7f53000-f7f54000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 POWERPNT.EXE
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000023    0
    0000001e    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    0000001d    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001c    0
00000021 winedevice.exe
    00000028    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000022    0
00000029 explorer.exe
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
0000002e (D) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE
    00000036    1
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
    00000033    0
    00000032    0
    00000031    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-3.4
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.4.0-45-generic
```