# winbind error - unable to setup corepath

Tags: 20.04, playonlinux

Am trying to install MS Office 2016 by following the guide here:
[How do I install MS Office 2016 on PlayOnLinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975104/how-do-i-install-ms-office-2016-on-playonlinux)

However under preparations step 1, when I run the "winbindd -V" command I get the following error:

```
kieran@kieran-Inspiron-3268:~$ winbindd -V
Failed to create /var/log/samba/cores for user 1000 with mode 0700
Unable to setup corepath for winbindd: No such file or directory
Version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: At a first glance, it seems to be working as the version is outputted correctly, but failed to log to the samba log while doing that. I don't know if this is expected or not though.