# How to remove these dependencies (installed with wine-stable:i386 smbclient winbind)

Tags: apt, 20.04, kubuntu, wine, dependencies

Testing if Office 2016 can be installed on Kubuntu 20.04 as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233780/925128), at some point I had to install `wine-stable:i386 smbclient winbind`. Seeing there were a lot of dependencies, I've made a note of those in case I want them removed.

And I do (msoffice_2016 installation failed, I have dual boot etc).

Those dependencies are (be very scared!):

```
> fonts-wine gcc-10-base:i386 glib-networking:i386
> gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386
> gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386
> libaa1:i386 libaom0:i386 libapparmor1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
> libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386
> libatomic1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
> libavahi-common3:i386 libavc1394-0:i386 libavcodec58:i386
> libavutil56:i386 libblkid1:i386 libbrotli1:i386 libbsd0:i386
> libbz2-1.0:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
> libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
> libcdparanoia0:i386 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcrypt1:i386
> libcups2:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3:i386
> libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
> libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386
> libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfaudio0
> libfaudio0:i386 libffi7:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
> libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc-s1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386
> libgd3:i386 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
> libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
> libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386
> libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error-l10n
> libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386
> libgpm2:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
> libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
> libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
> libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
> libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed5:i386
> libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu66:i386 libidn2-0:i386
> libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11:i386
> libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
> libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
> libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
> libllvm12:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386
> libmount1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmysqlclient21:i386
> libncurses6:i386 libncursesw6:i386 libnettle7:i386 libnghttp2-14:i386
> libnuma1:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
> libopenjp2-7:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6
> libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
> libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
> libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre3:i386
> libperl5.30:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libproxy1v5:i386
> libpsl5:i386 libpulse0:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
> librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
> libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
> libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386
> libsensors5:i386 libshine3:i386 libshout3:i386 libslang2:i386
> libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp35:i386
> libsoup2.4-1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
> libssh-4:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libstb0 libstb0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
> libswresample3:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtag1v5:i386
> libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386
> libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libudev1:i386
> libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386
> libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
> libvdpau1:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386
> libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx6:i386 libvulkan1:i386
> libwavpack1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
> libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386
> libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine libwine:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
> libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179:i386 libxau6:i386
> libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
> libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
> libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386
> libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
> libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386
> libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
> libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
> libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386
> libzvbi0:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
> mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 va-driver-all:i386
> vdpau-driver-all:i386 wine wine32:i386 wine64 zlib1g:i386 Suggested
> packages: gvfs:i386 i965-va-driver-shaders:i386 glibc-doc:i386
> locales:i386 libdv-bin:i386 oss-compat:i386 rng-tools:i386
> libgd-tools:i386 gdbm-l10n:i386 gnutls-bin:i386 gphoto2:i386 gpm:i386
> krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386
> gstreamer1.0-tools:i386 jackd2:i386 libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc
> unixodbc-bin libmyodbc:i386 odbc-postgresql:i386 tdsodbc:i386
> unixodbc-bin:i386 libportaudio2:i386 opus-tools:i386
> libraw1394-doc:i386 librsvg2-bin:i386 hplip:i386
> libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386 |  libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386
> libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-sql:i386 lm-sensors:i386
> sndiod:i386 speex:i386 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
> gstreamer1.0-libav:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386
> gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:i386 ttf-mscorefonts-installer:i386
> opencl-icd:i386 libvdpau-va-gl1:i386 nvidia-vdpau-driver:i386
> nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver:i386
> nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver:i386 libnss-winbind libpam-winbind
> q4wine winetricks playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox wine32-preloader:i386
> wine64-preloader The following NEW packages will be installed:
> fonts-wine gcc-10-base:i386 glib-networking:i386
> gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386
> gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386
> libaa1:i386 libaom0:i386 libapparmor1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
> libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386
> libatomic1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
> libavahi-common3:i386 libavc1394-0:i386 libavcodec58:i386
> libavutil56:i386 libblkid1:i386 libbrotli1:i386 libbsd0:i386
> libbz2-1.0:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
> libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
> libcdparanoia0:i386 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcrypt1:i386
> libcups2:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3:i386
> libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
> libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386
> libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfaudio0
> libfaudio0:i386 libffi7:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
> libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc-s1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386
> libgd3:i386 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
> libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
> libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386
> libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error-l10n
> libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386
> libgpm2:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
> libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
> libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
> libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
> libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed5:i386
> libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu66:i386 libidn2-0:i386
> libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11:i386
> libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
> libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
> libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
> libllvm12:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386
> libmount1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmysqlclient21:i386
> libncurses6:i386 libncursesw6:i386 libnettle7:i386 libnghttp2-14:i386
> libnuma1:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
> libopenjp2-7:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6
> libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
> libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
> libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre3:i386
> libperl5.30:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libproxy1v5:i386
> libpsl5:i386 libpulse0:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
> librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
> libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
> libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386
> libsensors5:i386 libshine3:i386 libshout3:i386 libslang2:i386
> libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp35:i386
> libsoup2.4-1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
> libssh-4:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libstb0 libstb0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
> libswresample3:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtag1v5:i386
> libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386
> libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libudev1:i386
> libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386
> libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
> libvdpau1:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386
> libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx6:i386 libvulkan1:i386
> libwavpack1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
> libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386
> libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine libwine:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
> libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179:i386 libxau6:i386
> libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
> libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
> libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386
> libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
> libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386
> libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
> libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
> libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386
> libzvbi0:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
> mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 va-driver-all:i386
> vdpau-driver-all:i386 winbind wine wine-stable wine32:i386 wine64
> zlib1g:i386
```

When I try to run `sudo apt remove` on those, I get first this nocturnal warning:

[image]

then:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386: command not found
E: Unable to locate package Suggested
E: Unable to locate package packages:
```

If I do it in brackets: `sudo apt remove "ALL THOSE"`, I get:

```
> E: Unable to locate package fonts-wine gcc-10-base:i386
> glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
> gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386
> intel-media-va-driver:i386 libaa1:i386 libaom0:i386 libapparmor1:i386
> libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
> libasyncns0:i386 libatomic1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
> libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavc1394-0:i386
> libavcodec58:i386 libavutil56:i386 libblkid1:i386 libbrotli1:i386
> libbsd0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386
> libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3
> libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcodec2-0.9:i386
> libcom-err2:i386 libcrypt1:i386 libcups2:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386
> libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
> libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386
> libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386
> libexpat1:i386 libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libffi7:i386 libflac8:i386
> libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc-s1:i386
> libgcrypt20:i386 libgd3:i386 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386
> libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
> libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386
> libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386
> libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386
> libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386
> libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
> libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
> libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
> libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
> libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed5:i386
> libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu66:i386 libidn2-0:i386
> libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11:i386
> libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
> libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
> libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
> libllvm12:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386
> libmount1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmysqlclient21:i386
> libncurses6:i386 libncursesw6:i386 libnettle7:i386 libnghttp2-14:i386
> libnuma1:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
> libopenjp2-7:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6
> libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
> libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
> libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre3:i386
> libperl5.30:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libproxy1v5:i386
> libpsl5:i386 libpulse0:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
> librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
> libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
> libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386
> libsensors5:i386 libshine3:i386 libshout3:i386 libslang2:i386
> libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp35:i386
> libsoup2.4-1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
> libssh-4:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libstb0 libstb0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
> libswresample3:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtag1v5:i386
> libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386
> libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libudev1:i386
> libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386
> libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
> libvdpau1:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386
> libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx6:i386 libvulkan1:i386
> libwavpack1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
> libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386
> libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine libwine:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
> libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179:i386 libxau6:i386
> libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
> libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
> libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386
> libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
> libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386
> libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
> libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
> libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386
> libzvbi0:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
> mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 va-driver-all:i386
> vdpau-driver-all:i386 wine wine32:i386 wine64 zlib1g:i386 Suggested
> packages: gvfs:i386 i965-va-driver-shaders:i386 glibc-doc:i386
> locales:i386 libdv-bin:i386 oss-compat:i386 rng-tools:i386
> libgd-tools:i386 gdbm-l10n:i386 gnutls-bin:i386 gphoto2:i386 gpm:i386
> krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386
> gstreamer1.0-tools:i386 jackd2:i386 libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc
> unixodbc-bin libmyodbc:i386 odbc-postgresql:i386 tdsodbc:i386
> unixodbc-bin:i386 libportaudio2:i386 opus-tools:i386
> libraw1394-doc:i386 librsvg2-bin:i386 hplip:i386
> libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386 |  libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386
> libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-sql:i386 lm-sensors:i386
> sndiod:i386 speex:i386 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
> gstreamer1.0-libav:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386
> gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:i386 ttf-mscorefonts-installer:i386
> opencl-icd:i386 libvdpau-va-gl1:i386 nvidia-vdpau-driver:i386
> nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver:i386
> nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver:i386 libnss-winbind libpam-winbind
> q4wine winetricks playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox wine32-preloader:i386
> wine64-preloader The following NEW packages will be installed:
> fonts-wine gcc-10-base:i386 glib-networking:i386
> gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386
> gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386
> libaa1:i386 libaom0:i386 libapparmor1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
> libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386
> libatomic1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
> libavahi-common3:i386 libavc1394-0:i386 libavcodec58:i386
> libavutil56:i386 libblkid1:i386 libbrotli1:i386 libbsd0:i386
> libbz2-1.0:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
> libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
> libcdparanoia0:i386 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcrypt1:i386
> libcups2:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3:i386
> libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
> libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386
> libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfaudio0
> libfaudio0:i386 libffi7:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
> libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc-s1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386
> libgd3:i386 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
> libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
> libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386
> libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error-l10n
> libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386
> libgpm2:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
> libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
> libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
> libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
> libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed5:i386
> libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu66:i386 libidn2-0:i386
> libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11:i386
> libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
> libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
> libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
> libllvm12:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386
> libmount1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmysqlclient21:i386
> libncurses6:i386 libncursesw6:i386 libnettle7:i386 libnghttp2-14:i386
> libnuma1:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
> libopenjp2-7:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6
> libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
> libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
> libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre3:i386
> libperl5.30:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libproxy1v5:i386
> libpsl5:i386 libpulse0:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
> librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
> libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
> libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386
> libsensors5:i386 libshine3:i386 libshout3:i386 libslang2:i386
> libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp35:i386
> libsoup2.4-1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
> libssh-4:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libstb0 libstb0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
> libswresample3:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtag1v5:i386
> libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386
> libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libudev1:i386
> libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386
> libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
> libvdpau1:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386
> libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx6:i386 libvulkan1:i386
> libwavpack1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
> libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386
> libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine libwine:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
> libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179:i386 libxau6:i386
> libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
> libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
> libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386
> libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
> libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386
> libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
> libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
> libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386
> libzvbi0:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
> mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 va-driver-all:i386
> vdpau-driver-all:i386 winbind wine wine-stable wine32:i386 wine64
> zlib1g:i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep ":i386" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

before you do you can let show which packages are 32-bit.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep ":i386"
```

```
    awk '{print $1}'
```

print only the 1. field (here the packagename:i386)