# Set "Ubuntu On Xorg" by default globally but without preventing the choice of Wayland

Tags: xorg, 22.04, wayland

On this site:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/

I was told the way to set `Ubuntu on Xorg` by default in the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`:

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

But it doesn't work.
The name `ubuntu-xorg.desktop` I took it from the path `/usr/share/xsessions`.
Uncommenting (as the guide explains) or not the `WaylandEnable=false` line, the `DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop` line has no effect.

I don't want the option `Wayland` to disappear (uncommenting the line `WaylandEnable=false`), I just want that when creating any user (therefore for all users, therefore globally) `Ubuntu on Xorg` is selected as default is not `Ubuntu` (Ubuntu on Wayland).
Which file should I go to touch?

Don't tell me `/var/lib/AccountService/users/<user>` because I've already pointed out that I want to set this option globally but I don't want a way that uses the `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` file to do this if there is an already foreseen and more appropriate method.

Comment: Please correct some of the wording in your question: the site did not say that adding only that line was enough or would work (which you now seem to imply). It only dealt with the case where you both set `WaylandEnable=false` and add the line.

Comment: Uncommenting (as the guide explains) or not the `WaylandEnable=false` line, the `DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop` line has no effect.

Comment: Someone can hel me?

Comment: I followed the (very simple) instructions given on the website (https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/) you quoted and it didn't work initially. I did not deviate from the instructions provided in the link. However, I restarted my PC as a last ditch effort before reverting my changes and it worked. So, perhaps, a full reboot is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I had upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and this approach worked for me on 22.04:

1. Confirm you're on Wayland. Typing `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` in a terminal should return `wayland`.
2. Backup the configuration file: `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf /etc/gdm3/custom.bak`.
3. Edit file: `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.
4. Insert new line `DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop`. It should look something like this:

[image]

4. Reboot and `Ubuntu On Xorg` is now selected by default at the Ubuntu 22.04 login screen, and `Ubuntu` (on Wayland) is still available as an option.

[image]